# Embedded Collection of Same Type

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, nosql

I have a document called 'Field' in my collection.  I need to embed a collection of Field children in a Field. I'm using GORM to handle the domain modeling and persist to the collection and everything appears to be saving fine.  When I query the collection however I'm noticing something isn't right:

```
/* 11 */
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(11),
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-08-28T08:42:39.511-04:00"),
    "description" : "An embedded fieldset",
    "fields" : [ 
        NumberLong(12), 
        NumberLong(13)
    ],
    "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2017-08-28T08:42:39.511-04:00"),
    "name" : "embeddedFieldset",
}

/* 12 */
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(14),
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-08-28T08:42:39.512-04:00"),
    "description" : "Favorite Number?",
    "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2017-08-28T08:42:39.512-04:00"),
    "name" : "favoriteNumber",
}
```

Notice that the Field with id 11 has 2 embedded fields (with ids 12 and 13), but the very next field in the collection has an id of 14.  So it certainly looks like 12 and 13 exist, but I don't see them in the collection at all.  So, where are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.  There was an error in the embedded Fields that was preventing them from saving to the database.